# SwiftUI : How to Fix leading and trailing with margin 10

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

This is my first trial on SwiftUI, where I am trying to create a UITable view like UI.
I am trying to give fix leading and trailing (not fix width) to cell/views, I have given ample of time and now this is what I have tried with output:
[image]

Git : [Here is the link to source code to reproduce this issue](https://github.com/alok1upadhyay/SwiftUI)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to use `.padding` modifier for margin. In your code, you have to add padding inside your ScrollView.

```
{
            VStack(alignment: .center){
             ForEach(boxes) { box in
              BoxViewTable(box: box)
                .background(Color.white).padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
             }
```

After that, inside BoxViewTable, you need to add .frame modifier.

```
 HStack{

      Image("\(box.imgUrl)")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 80, height: 100, alignment: .leading)

      VStack(alignment:.leading){
        Text("\(box.newsTitle)")
          .lineLimit(2)
        Text("\(box.newsSubTitle) - \(box.dateTime)")
      }

    }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
```

Finally, Don't give up :-)